# Parse XML object from XLIFF file C#

Tags: c#, xml, xliff

I am trying to Parse XML object with two namespaces inside the file.

```xml
<xliff srcLang="en" version="23.0"
  xmlns="asd:asd:asd:asd:xliff:document:23.0"
  xmlns:mda="asd:asd:asd:asd:xliff:document:23.0">   
    <file id="f"
      original="someUrl">
        <unit id="1" name="air">
          <mda:data>
            <mda:group category="attributes">
               <mda:meta type="id">Color</mda:meta>
               <mda:meta type="abbr">I_AI_LOW</mda:meta>
               <mda:meta type="type">Message</mda:meta>
             </mda:group>
           </mda:data>
           <segment>
             <source>Too many messages for 1 minute</source>
           </segment>
         </unit>   
    </file> 
</xliff>
```

I want to take the value from **unit id="1" name="air**" from property name, "**mda:meta type="type" property type** and **source>Too many messages for 1 minute - property segment**. I want to assign their value to other properties, so basically to extract their value.

My code now is:

```
 xliff = XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath(filePath));
 var ns = xliff.Root!.Name.Namespace;

 var elements = xliff.Descendants()
            .Elements(ns + "unit").ToList();

//this part not working
XElement tempElement = elements.Descendants(XName.Get("mda:metadata", 
ns.ToString())).FirstOrDefault()!;
```

I know that somehow I have to access the second namespace, but I don't know how to do it.
Any help here will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `XNamespace` and `LINQ`

```
XNamespace ns1 = "asd:asd:asd:asd:xliff:document:23.0";
XNamespace ns2 = "asd:asd:asd:asd:xliff:document:23.0";

var type_value = xliff.Descendants(ns1 + "unit")
    .Descendants(ns2 + "meta")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("type") == "type")
    .Select(y => y.Value)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .ToString();
```

OR (to get all values to list)

```
var elements =  xliff.Descendants(ns1 + "unit")
    .Descendants(ns2 + "meta")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("type") == "type")
    .Select(y => y.Value.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

OR (to get source from segment)

```
var nameSegment = xliff.Descendants(ns1 + "unit")
    .Descendants(ns1 + "segment")
    .Select(x => x.Element(ns1 + "source").Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: There should be no values into linq, as I want to assign the value of each to another object. If you can provide example without ==1 and ==air

Comment: @Sarah just remove where clause

Comment: Can you write the same for source and name ,which I think comes from unit?

Comment: I need all values from the file for them into list.

Comment: @Sarah, Possible.. have updated the post

Comment: var nameSegment = xliff.Descendants(x + "unit")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("segment") == "segment")
                .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
                .ToList();

not working with segment

Comment: @Sarah, updated the post to get all segment source values. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            XDocument xliff = XDocument.Load(Path.GetFullPath(filePath));
            XNamespace ns = xliff.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
            XNamespace nsMda = xliff.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("mda");

            List<XElement> elements = xliff.Descendants(ns + "unit").ToList();

            //this part not working
            List<XElement> metaData = elements.Descendants(nsMda +  "metadata").ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this works for the namespace, but if you can help a little bit more, how could I take only the described above properties ?